# Como preencher automaticamente um campo?

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulário onde quero pedir o **Distrito** e **Concelho** utilizando o código Postal e aparecendo os campos que quero com preenchimento automático.

Por exemplo:

A pessoa coloca o Código postal "5489-698" e Aparece distrito e Concelho automaticamente.

Já fiz o download do arquivo(txt) com os códigos postais.

Alguém já fez isso?

Comment: Quer fazer isso do lado do servidor ou cliente? Pode colocar um excerto do tipo de dados que o arquivo de códigos postais têm?

Comment: Qual o tamanho desse arquivo .txt? Dependendo do tamanho, se for acima de 1MB, a melhor estratégia é deixar os dados no servidor.

Comment: o tamanho é de 5,55KB . Consigo por o codigo php e ir buscar a informação ao doxumentos txt?

Comment: Apenas à nível de informação, `concelho` é como falam `município` em Portugal. Pesquisei para saber isso pois estava me soando estranho.

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de preenchimento é feito com ajax, não é necessário ter uma base local com os dado pois é possível utilizar a api dos correios.

Segue um link com uma ótima explicação e tutorial.

http://novos-cientistas.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/webservice-utilizando-api-dos-correios.html

Comment: Vale a pena pensar se a aplicação dele apesar de web, não trabalhará off-line / intranet.

Answer (score 0):

O melhor a fazer é criar uma tabela na base de dados e inserir todos os códigos postais com os respectivos distritos e concelhos.

No HTML faça o seguinte, após o cliente preencher o campo utilize o AJAX para fazer uma requisição ao um PHP passando como parâmetro o código postal preenchido.
O PHP faz uma busca a base de dados pelo código postal e retorna o distrito e o concelho ou um erro caso não encontre nada. Faça um retorno em JSON, é melhor.

Faça a requisição ajax somente depois de ter todos os caracteres preenchidos, se fizer um request a cada carácter preenchido vai sobrecarregar o servidor sem necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Seria muito interessante conhecer como está organizado o arquivo txt com as informações postais.

Aqui no Brasil há um Web Service gratuito disponível no [República Virtual](http://republicavirtual.com.br/cep/) que talvez possa ser útil. Lá tem várias explicações e exemplos de como utilizar em diversas linguagens.

Há também o GeoNames, internacional, e vários outros Web Services disponíveis com uma lista de vários países. Seria interessante pesquisar mais depois.

Se ainda assim precisar utilizar o arquivo txt, tente o seguinte. Na maioria das vezes são arquivos do tipo CSV (Valores Separados por Vírgula). Tem uma publicação muito boa [neste blog](http://rubsphp.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/arquivos-csv.html) sobre como utilizar esse tipo de arquivo no PHP; passando para um Array você pode percorrê-lo em busca da informação.

Independente da forma com a qual conseguir extrair os dados da tabela de dados, vai precisar de JavaScript para construir uma função AJAX que insira os dados automaticamente. Como fazer isso?

Primeiramente crie os campos em seu HTML e dê um ID diferente e específico a cada um deles. Ex.:

```
<input type="text" id="codigo-postal" /><br />
<input type="text" id="concelho" />
```

Depois crie um evento para quando o usuário sair do campo codigo-postal os dados serem pesquisados e preenchidos automaticamente. Para facilitar, poderemos utilizar a biblioteca JavaScript jQuery.

```
$("#codigo-postal").focusout(function() {
    $.getJSON( "busca_codigo.php", {
        codigo: $("#codigo-postal")[0].value
        } )
        .done(function( data ) {
            if(data.encontrou == 1) {
                $("#concelho")[0].value = data.conselho
            } else {
                alert("Código não encontrado!");
            }
    });
});
```

Um detalhe importante e que facilita bastante o trabalho é que os dados estão sendo repassados no formato JSON. Um Array de dados dessa forma pode ser facilmente obtido através do PHP e facilmente tratado através do JavaScript.

Pode ser que, dependendo da base de dados, a busca iterativa no arquivo txt fique um pouco lenta e consuma muitos recursos do servidor. Procure utilizar um Web Service de confiança que já existe ou migrar os dados para um Banco de Dados SQL, por exemplo; algo que ofereça uma busca mais otimizada.

O endereço da API que é colocado no começo da função jQuery.getJSON deve estar sob o mesmo domínio que a página HTML. Por questões de segurança os navegadores web modernos bloqueiam o acesso a endereços externos através dessas funções. Portanto, se for utilizar alguma API/Web Service externo, ainda assim escreva um script PHP para que pegue esses dados e repasse ao JavaScript.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: mas tambem poderei colocar por exemplo um botão perto da zona do código postal para a pessoa colocar o Numero e clicar no botão

Comment: Sim, perfeitamente.
Basta substituir a primeira linha `$("#codigo-postal").focusout(function() {` por `$("#botao").click(function() {`

Comment: Basta um botão simples?
<button type="button"  style='width: 100px' value="#botao">Automático</button>

Comment: Sim :)
Resolve seu problema?

Comment: Só um pequeno detalhe, não seria `value="#botao"` no seu código, mas sim `id="botao"`.